# pandas diff between within successive groups

Tags: pandas, diff

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'a':[7,6,3,4,8], 'b':['c','c','d','d','c']})
d.groupby('b')['a'].diff()
```

Gives me

```
0    NaN
1   -1.0
2    NaN
3    1.0
4    2.0
```

What I'd need

```
0    NaN
1   -1.0
2    NaN
3    1.0
4    NaN
```

Which is difference between only successive values within group, so when a group appears after another group , it's previous values are ignored.

In my example last `c` value is a new `c` group.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to `groupby` on consecutive segments

```
In [1055]: d.groupby((d.b != d.b.shift()).cumsum())['a'].diff()
Out[1055]:
0    NaN
1   -1.0
2    NaN
3    1.0
4    NaN
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Details

```
In [1056]: (d.b != d.b.shift()).cumsum()
Out[1056]:
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
Name: b, dtype: int32
```